# QWebView doesn't load a page on windows

Tags: qt, webkit, webview, qwebview

I have a problem with QWebView. It doesn't load http://mail.bigmir.net/signin/ this page on Windows. I tried load it on application written on Windows, on Linux, and Windows and Linux. But that same code load this page on Linux. Why? What I do badly?

I thought that is my QtCreator fault because on Linux I had 2.0.1 and on Windows I had 2.0.0 but after update it to 2.0.1 on Windows nothing changed ;[ 
I add that I have version from September on Linux, and August on Windows, but i downloaded the newest package from qt.nokia.com for Windows.

Update to QtCreator 2.1 nothing changed too. This website can't load ;[ I ran example browser and it doesn't load it too ;[ Now I have the newer version on Windows than on Linux, and it still doesn't work.

I think, on Windows my QWebView can't redirect (it's google's security with hundred redirects...) so i stay in one place and can't go next(/forward).

Anyone know how to unlock it on Windows or something like that? I need it to work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to wager that it redirects to a `https://` URL, and you don't have OpenSSL installed in windows and QT isn't built to use it. You need to get OpenSSL and configure QT to use it.

Here's a quick result from google:

http://greensoftware.net/blog/2009/12/01/compiling-qt4-6-with-openssl-support-on-windows-with-mingw/

(Google `QT with openssl windows` and you'll find lots of info)